# boost::split return sep character

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, boost, split

I am using `boost::split(lines, str, boost::is_any_of(delims));` Now I want to know which delim character was found against each split. and I'll put  that character at the end of the splitted lines. so that I can recreate the original string. I've searched but haven't found any such feature in `boost::split` Do I need to use any other function ?

Answer (score 1):

mb `boost::tokenizer` with `boost::char_separator`?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm

Example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
   std::string str = "hello, and what do. you? want";
   typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
   boost::char_separator<char> sep("", " ,.?");
   tokenizer tokens(str, sep);
   for (tokenizer::iterator pos = tokens.begin(); pos != tokens.end(); ++pos)
   {
      std::cout << *pos << std::endl;
   }
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/8dca20ecaa017000dd67096fc5d20aeb

Comment: How would I differentiate between a seperator token and the text in middle ?

Comment: @DiproSen copy separators in one container and copy words in other container, for example.

Comment: How will I do that ? would I need to put every even item in seperator container ?

Comment: @DiproSen move separators from returned container to other container for example. Is it problem for you?

Comment: `tokens` is the what your are calling returned container ? So to move seperators I need to rely on the fact that every even item is the seperator ? right

Comment: @DiproSen tokens is returning container - right. why every even item? use predicate (for example `boost::is_any_of`).

Comment: I want to know which seperator terminated the splitted part. e.g. I'll store the splitted part and seperator symbol in a pair, (so that I can recreate the original string latter). so every even item is the splitted part and every odd item is the seperator. This is what I need to honour ? right ?

Comment: @DiproSen separator can be not one character, but more than one.

Comment: in your example its one character only. buts thats not what I am asking. What I am asking is do I need to obey that every even element 0,2,4 .... will be a splitted part. and every odd element e.g. 1,3,5 is the seperator ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16311/discussion-between-forever-and-dipro-sen)